# Money exchange for my friend in delhi. She is waiting for exchange her pounds

Tags: foreign-exchange

One of my friends comes from Romania.  She will exchange some pounds to Indian rupees. What she will do?

Comment: Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! It's not really clear what kind of answer you're looking for (beyond "she will give someone (e.g. bank, currency exchange service at airport, etc.) pounds, and they will give her rupees", which I assume you already understand). Could you please [edit](https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/105551/edit) your question to explain what part of the process you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit unclear what you are asking, but I will assume you ask for the best (cheapest) options to exchange money.

Most of the time, it is cheaper to exchange in the target country - so if she needs Indian Rupees, she should 'buy' them in India. Also, it is illegal to bring larger amounts of Indian Rupees into India, so exchanging before the trip is not really an option anyway.

She should - if she has the option - consider bringing a common currency, like US dollar, Euros, or British Pound. Bringing rarer currency from a small country (like Romanian Leu) might result in many or all exchange shop not taking it.
Have clean bills in good condition, and not too large denominations (value of ~20 Euro/US$ or less).

Exchange is possibly at the airport, in many bigger hotels, and - probably best - in little street shops in big cities.